selected value coming as null in primeng multiselect
Dynamically selected Value showing as null in primeng multiselect.
here is my code,
<p-multiSelect 
  [options]="horses"
  [(ngModel)]="horse_ids"
  placeholder="Select Horse"
  optionLabel="horse_name"
  class="form-control w-100"
  filterPlaceHolder="Search Horse"
  [maxSelectedLabels]="3"
  selectedItemsLabel="{0} horses selected"
  (onChange)="horseselect()"
>
<p-mutliSelect>

Im using ngModel directive which have data of selected options but it shows null, Anyone knows some about this?

Hey, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please elaborate a bit more on what exactly is showing as null. The .ts part of horseselect may be helpful as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm sorry, in the onChange event I took a log of horse_ids which contains an array of the selected horse's entire object, and hoses are an array of horses that contain name, images, and id.
